# Hosting a native control in WPF

Tags: c++, wpf, controls

I have a native control, written in C++ and using DirectX 11, that I would like to embed within a WPF application. Currently the control is hosted in a Windows Store app, and that works fine. I mention this in case Store App compatibility is important.

Based on [Hosting Win32 Content in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970061.aspx), my understanding is that because WPF performs its own composition, and has a single window handle, the core complication is providing another window handle to the native control. Therefore, the solution is to add to the WPF page either a WindowsFormHost control or a control that derives from HwndHost and somehow associate the WPF control with the native control.

I went through the [Hosting a Win32 Control  in WPF walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752055%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, my control is not registered with the OS the way ListBox (the control used in the example) is. So, I cannot pass it as an argument to CreateWindowEx. How can I associate my own control? Do I create a WindowsFormsHost and call SetParent(myControlsHandle, windowsFormsHost.Handle)? Or do I create a WPF Border and set its Child property to a HwndHost instance?

There are other questions related to native controls in WPF ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493082/native-win32-window-in-wpf-control) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window), though the latter is about applications, not controls), but none address this question.

I looked into a different approach, where a WPF control shares a D3DImage with the native control, but that requires DirectX9EX, and my control is written in Dx11.

Answer (score 0):

Found an article in msdn.hope this helps.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)